Como pasarle las respuestas OCSP a itext7 en C# (IOCSPClient)
Estoy tratando de validar un certificado X509 instalado en el store de Windows con la finalidad de validar la revocación del certificado para efectos de firma digital . Tengo este código para obtener las respuestas OCSP del servidor:
async Task<BasicOcspResp> PostReqHTTP(OcspReqBC req, string urlOcsp)
{
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
    {
        criterios, de lo contrario false.
        return true; 
    };
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, urlOcsp)
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(req.GetEncoded())
    };
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/ocsp-response"));
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/ocsp-request");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

    //Leer respuesta
    byte[] responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

    OcspResp ocspResp = new OcspResp(responseData);
    BasicOcspResp basicResp = (BasicOcspResp)ocspResp.GetResponseObject();


    if (ocspResp.Status == OcspRespStatus.Successful)
    {
        foreach (SingleResp single in basicResp.Responses)
        {

            //SingleResponse singleResponse = new SingleResponse(single);
            //SingleResponseBC singleResponseBC = new SingleResponseBC(singleResponse);
        }

    }

    return null;
}

Sin embargo eso me devuelve un BasicOcspResp del namespace Org.BouncyCastle.Ocsp y yo lo que necesito es pasar esas respuestas a una lista de : IList basicOcspResponses = new List(); que es de la biblioteca itext7 especificamente del namespace: iText.Commons.Bouncycastle.Asn1.Ocsp. Como lo hago ? Como convierto ese BasicOcspResp en un IBasicOcspResponse o como obtengo un IBasicOcspResponse a partir de un BasicOcspResp . He buscado en la documentacion y no hay ejemplos de como hacerlo.

Pero cual seria el problema???

Ya modifique la pregunta
